# Canvas / Возможно ли отслеживания изменения фона под canvas и реагировать на это?

Tags: javascript, canvas, iframe, watermark, videojs

Всем привет, появилась такая нетривиальная задача, необходимо реализовать средствами JS.

Условие - иметься `iframe` в середине которого играется видео (фон динамически меняется, доступа к самому видео нету... что будет в следующем кадре контролировать нельзя), вопрос есть ли возможность добавить некий элемент (что-то по типу `watermark`) который мог бы отслеживать изменение пикселей ПОД этим водяным знаком и как-то реагировать на это самим водяным знаком. В качестве примитивного примера вот

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let image = document.getElementById('source');
  ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  animation: bgAnimation 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bgAnimation {
  0%,
  100% {
    background: #f00;
  }
  50% {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas">
            <img id="source" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg"
                 width="300" height="300" alt="rino">
        </canvas>
</div>
```

Возможно ли определить, предположим, что если под `canvas` фон начинает краснеть, то и само изображение делать более красным ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение заключается в отрисовке видео на канвасе `Canvas2dcontext.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, heigth);`, потому что на него не как не влияют цвета под ним.

Помимо этого нужно разрешить считывать данные изображения при условии что видео не находится в том же домене (видимо защита прав) делается это `video.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');`

Средний цвет высчитывается среднеарифметическим способом, для ускорения пропускаются пиксели. Знаю, еще есть вариант сжимать и растягивать картинку, но предпочел классику, хотя в целях оптимизации возможно будет работать шустрее.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const SPEED_MS = 250;
const videoId = 'video';
const video = document.getElementById(videoId);
/* prevent security error, img on diff domain */
video.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');

function capture(video) {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const w = video.videoWidth;
  const h = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
  avgColor(ctx, w, h) 
}

function shoot() {
  capture(video);
}

function rgbToString(rgb){
  return `rgb(${rgb.r},${rgb.g},${rgb.b})`
}

function avgColor(ctx, width, height){
  const blockSize = 10
  const rgb = {r: 255, g: 0, b: 0}
  try {
    data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  } catch(e) {
    /* security error, img on diff domain */
    output.style.background = rgbToString(rgb);
    return; 
  }
  length = data.data.length;
  let i = 0;
  let count = 0;
  while ((i += blockSize * 4) < length) {
    ++count;
    rgb.r += data.data[i];
    rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
    rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
  }
  rgb.r = Math.floor(rgb.r / count);
  rgb.g = Math.floor(rgb.g / count);
  rgb.b = Math.floor(rgb.b / count);
  output.style.background = rgbToString(rgb);
} 

setInterval(() => shoot(), SPEED_MS);
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
canvas{
  display: none;
}
#output {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Average color</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <video id="video" width="320" height="180" controls="true">
      <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video tag. Please download FireFox 3.5 or higher.
    </video>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```